# ROS: Subscribe to the same callback and same topic (with different index) assign to correspondig variables

Tags: callback, argument-passing, ros, subscribe

I have 10 robots in stage ROS and want to subscribe the topic of position `/base_pose_ground_truth`. It means I must subscribe to `robot0_base_pose_ground_truth`, `robot1_base_pose_ground_truth`, ....

The first solution coming to mind is:

```
for(int i=0; i<RobotNumber; i++) {                  
  char str[30] = "/robot_";
  char index[4];
  sprintf(index, "%d", i);
  strcat(str, index);
  strcat(str, "/base_pose_ground_truth");
  GoalPos_sub[i] = Node.subscribe(str, 100, GetPos_callback);           
}
```

and the callback could be:

```
void GetPos_callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg) {
  Goalpose[0] = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
  Goalpose[1] = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
}
```

But this will not give me 10 different position corresponding to each robot. I don't know how I can put the position of each robot in its corresponding memory (for example array or vector). It might be possible by passing the robot index as an argument to the callback and try to use it for assigning the position topic to an array.

I will be thankful if some one help me in this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are already very close to the solution: You can indeed add the robot index as an argument to the callback and change `Goalpose` to be an array:

```
void GetPos_callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg, int index) {
  Goalpose[index][0] = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
  Goalpose[index][1] = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
}
```

You have to change the subscribe command a bit to make this work. To pass the index to the callback, you have to use `boost::bind`:

```
GoalPos_sub[i] = Node.subscribe(str, 100, boost::bind(GetPos_callback, _1, i));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the previous answer is already pretty good. Therefore I just want to add here something that worked for me on ROS kinetic. Since the callback function now does not match the one from the subscribed topic you have to provide the data type.

In your case the modification would be:

```
GoalPos_sub[i] = Node.subscribe<nav_msgs::Odometry>(str, 100, boost::bind(GetPos_callback, _1, i));
```

I have found a [similar answer here](https://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber/?answer=63998#post-id-63998)